# Exception while reading data from JPA - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, lombok

I have a 2 entity classes.Employee and Account

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "org")
public class Employee {
@Id
@Column(name = "emp_id")
private String empId;

@Column(name = "emp_name")
private String empName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
private Set<Account> accounts;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@Table(name = "account", schema = "org")
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "acct_id")
private Integer accountId;

@Column(name = "acct_nbr")
private String accountNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
private Employee employee;
}
```

I am able to save data to database , however upon retrieval of employee row I get "**Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate Employee.toString()**" and for the collections in the employee object(accounts) I see "**Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.**"

I have tried with FetchType.EAGER for OnetoMany however no luck.Not sure if its the lombok @Data(toString())causing issue.

PS: I use JPA CrudRepository to save and retrieve data from DB.

please help.

Comment: One issue is you have cyclic dependencies for toString which might be causing the issue if its trying to log retrieved objects by printing them. If you call toString on account it will call toString on its owning employee which will call toString on all the accounts which contain it which will again call toString on itself, cycling like this until it runs out of memory. Also, can you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add the following annotation to `Employee`:

```
@ToString(exclude="accounts")
```

Also, I think you want to add base the equality of both entities based on their id:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="emp_id")
```

And something similar to `Account`

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: No luck with the above suggested change :( .

Comment: This worked for me on solving my cyclic dependencies for toString() on my entities in my integration test. One thing to note from this is the "accounts" and both of these are on the entity level. Is there a recommended way for Overriding the toString() behavior when already using the @Data annotation?